# Java Elements in List not "automatically updating"

Tags: java

First of all: I forgot the term for "automatically updating", but I mean this:

```
int x = 5;
int y = x;
System.out.println(y); //Prints 5
x = 3;
System.out.println(y); //Now prints 3!
```

(**NOTE for anyone using this as reference: Above example is wrong as addressed in comments.**)

However I tried this approach on a List, and it does not work, my code:

Relevant part of Account.java:

```
public class Account extends Entity<String, Account> {
    private String username;
    private String password;

    public Account(final String username, final String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;

        key = username;
        data.add(password);
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(final String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(final String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Relevant part of Entity.java:

```
abstract public class Entity<K, D> {
    protected K key;
    protected List<Object> data;

    public Entity() {
        data = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public K getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public List<Object> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    protected List<Object> createData(final DataAction dataAction) {
        List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
        if (dataAction == DataAction.INSERT) {
            list.add(key);
        }

        list.addAll(data);

        if (dataAction == DataAction.UPDATE) {
            list.add(key);
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

Whenever I have for example this `Account account = new Account("test", "1");`, and then when I use `System.out.println(account.getData())` it prints `[1]`, that still is correct. But when I execute `account.setPassword("11");` and then subsequently `System.out.println(account.getData())` it still prints `[1]` instead of the expected `[11]`.

I expected that `data` would be updated automatically just as `x = y` point to the same memory location.

Any guess what is going on? Error in implementation? Or feature? And how can I efficiently work around this?

Regards.

**EDIT:** Changed `setPassword()` to below code, now it should work:

```
public void setPassword(final String password) {
    int index = data.indexOf(this.password);
    this.password = password;
    data.set(index, password);
}
```

However I wonder, is there not a better solution to this? As it requires three lines of code now of which two of them can easily be forgotten.

Comment: You need to look up the difference between an object and an object reference to get to the root of your confusion.

Comment: Primitives in Java are _value_ types. Read up the official Java tutorial.

Comment: you code in the first part does not work too

Comment: As hoaz said, your initial code does not do what you said it does. I just checked. Your assumptions are wrong.

Comment: Added a proposed answer, help on it would be appreciated

Answer (score 7):

I think you're confused. This code:

```
int x = 5;
int y = x;
System.out.println(y); //Prints 5
x = 3;
System.out.println(y); //Now prints 3!
```

... will *not* print 3. This assignment:

```
int y = x;
```

... doesn't associate the `y` and `x` variables with each other. It *just* copies the current value of `x` into `y`. Further changes to `x` are *not* reflected in `y`.

Comment: I am pretty sure that I have had times when variables have changed exactly like I've described... Only I cannot recall a concrete example. Do you know if this actually is possible in Java with basic code?

Comment: @Aurand `Integer` is immutable and there's no difference.

Answer (score 0):

In your introductory example you have confused it with the case where `x` and `y` both point to the same mutable object and you change its state:

```
List<String> x = new ArrayList<>();
x.add("a");
y = x;
y.add("b");
System.out.println(y); // prints [a, b]
```

In your `Account` constructor you have both

```
    this.password = password;
```

and

```
    data.add(password);
```

but in `setPassword` you only have

```
    this.password = password;
```

Naturally, when you invoke `setPassword`, the contents of the `data` list are unaffected by it, and this is regardless of whether `password` is a primitive or reference type.

Answer (score 0):

> Whenever I have for example this Account account = new Account("test", "1");, and then when I use System.out.println(account.getData()) it prints [1], that still is correct. But when I execute account.setPassword("11"); and then subsequently System.out.println(account.getData()) it still prints [1] instead of the expected [11].

You're calling this setter:

```
public void setPassword(final String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
```

Which changes the "password" member.

Then you call the getter:

```
public List<Object> getData() {
    return data;
}
```

Why did you expect "data" to change after calling setPassword?

Comment: I expected that because (I thought that) `password` is an element of `data`, and thus (I thought that) when changing `password` in the `Account` object, it would also be changed in the `List` object.

Comment: You're confusing object assignment (which works by reference) and primitive assignment (which works by value). Changing "password" will make it refer to another String object. It will not change any other reference.

Answer (score 0):

Some types are 'mutable', so that you can change the value of a single object. Arrays are an example:

```
int[] x = new int[]{5};
int[] y = x;
System.out.println(y[0]); //Prints 5
x[0] = 3;
System.out.println(y[0]); //Now prints 3!
```

Compare with:

```
int[] x = new int[]{5};
int[] y = x;
System.out.println(y[0]); //Prints 5
x = new int[]{3};
System.out.println(y[0]); //Still prints 5!
```

`y = x` makes y refer, not to x but to the same value that x refers to. When I assign a new value to x, as I did in the second example, I'm making x refer to a different object than the one y now refers to. But, if I change that object itself, as I do with the first example, than both variables still refer to that same, now changed, object

Comment: Is there some way I can achieve this for my `password` in `Account` within `data` in `Entity`? So I'd need to reference the `password` in `data` in `Entity` to `password` in `Account`. Is that even possible? If so, how?